# windows phone 7 - Intermittent execution of JavaScript in WebBrowser

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-7.1

I have been playing around with the beta PhoneGap APIs for WP7 - and found that the execution of my JavaScript code is quiet intermittent. As a test-case I created a simple non-PhoneGap application and *still* see intermittent issues.

I have a browser control:

```
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="GapBrowser" 
                      Loaded="GapBrowser_Loaded" 
                      IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

And set its content in code-behind:

```
    private void GapBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GapBrowser.NavigateToString(@"
                <!doctype html>
                <html>
                <body>
                    Hello world
                    <div id='welcomeMsg'></div>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        document.getElementById('welcomeMsg').innerHTML += 'Script has executed!';
                    </script>
                </body>
                </html>
                ");
    }
```

This code should render a static 'Hello world' message, and when the script executes, appends 'Script has executed!'.

Sometimes (in fact quite often), for no apparent reason the JavaScript code is not being executed. Has anyone else observed this issue? Is it a bug, or is there some other lifecycle event I need to consider?

I am using the Mango emulator for my tests.

(Matt Lacey - I'm looking to you for answers on this one!)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this behaviour before , but,the fact you're not relying on any detection for the document being "ready" or the DOM fully loaded is the biggest red flag to me.

Out of interest do you also see this if loading a document via a call to `Navigate()`?
What if you have an event handler which calls back to the managed code on error? (As you couldn't display anything in the UI in such a situation.)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, on auto-firing scripts, there's almost no way to detect when the script engine terminates and what was the error. Practically, the only way to detect is attaching a WebBrowser.ScriptNotify event handler and injecting "window.external.notify('blahblah');" to every second line in the script.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Got an example where wrapping the code in a try..catch block and then outputting the exception details to the DOM doesn't work?

Comment: The problem I was referring to was the crash of the script engine, that occurs occasionally when a script tries to touch the 'body' tag right after the C# side receives "Navigated" event. The contents of HEAD tag is ok,but any action touching the BODY element causes the execution of JS to crash.I assume, that even if a try-catch handler in the JS catches that,it would still not be able to append anything since the BODY was out of order.I've been once forced to use that on SDK75.It could be related to a rare ScriptEnabled vs Source race condition.Drop me a note if you want details on the latter

Answer (score 0):

The idea that Matt's pointed out is great - and probably true, and I think it will get your script  running.

But, if it is not, then still I would think your script being called too fast, but with some other cause.

Inline scripts are executed (almost) immediatelly on being noticed, and the WebBrowser component has a bug/feature of ... being able to touch BODY elemet only after a certain, small period of time after having loaded the document. I've written on this extensively elsewhere, I can provide you a link if you are interested. The problem occurs mostly when trying to InvokeScript withing the Navigated event handler, but I assume it is some general internal race problem somewhere in the browser, so probably it could apply to your case too.

If the problem occurs, your scripts will throw a COM exception upon touching the BODY element. If it is done in InvokeScript - you will be notified about ugly and quite meaningless exception. But if it is in the script - for example auto-firing on body load, or in some JavaScript-Timer callback - then the browser will extinguish the exception and will silently cease to execute the script. Unfortunatelly, if it happens, the only way "around" this is detecting the problem, and repeating/delaying the call - or artificially delaying the call for about 125-250ms, and I mean, externally, not by JS-Timer, as a JS-Timer would catch the 'broken' (or rather not-ready) 'body'-reference in a closure. It happened to me exactly once on OS7.5.

Also, you can try moving the IsScriptEnabled=true as the first-just-after-the-x:Name. It may sound stupid, but believe me, the WebBrowser can have problems with that too. I can point you a link too, but it's mostly irrelevant now, please check it just to be sure. I am almost sure that your Loaded event handler is called with a correct timing, but if for some reason is not - this will instantly magically solve the problem.

//edit:
on the comment I've added to Matt's:

```
<WebBrowser (....) ScriptNotify="script_msg_handler" />
```

the handler:

```
private void script_msg_handler(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.WriteLine("WebBrwNotify:{0}", e.Value);
}
```

and modify the script to:

```
window.external.notify("0001");
var d = document;
window.external.notify("0002");
var elem = d.getElementById('welcomeMsg');
window.external.notify("0003");
elem.innerHTML += 'Script has executed!'
window.external.notify("0004");
```

Checking the Output window for such debug logs will show you whether the script is called at all, and which part of it caused it to crash. However, you will still be unable to detect exactly why, as some fo the exceptions are silenced by the *native* browser.